# Sitecore Core DB Items Changed Language?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Our Sitecore DB items had many of their display names changed to Japanese for no apparent reason. We thought that we might have accidentally changed the Sitecore language in the content editor, but I can confirm that it is in fact English. This seems to only be happening in the core DB. Has anyone had something similar happen?

Here is an example of the display name changing:

[image: Example]

Here is a confirmation that we are set to English:

[image: Language]

We're on Sitecore 7.5

Comment: so there are only some items in Core where this has happened? Do you have any tools like the https://github.com/Verndale-Corp/Sitecore-Language-Migration-Tool installed?

Comment: Did you accidentally copy over files from the Japanese version of Sitecore 7.5?

Comment: Also in configs, check for any reference to jp.

Answer (score 0):

There a 2 languages in the Sitecore CMS, the Content Language en the Client Language.

It looks like you change the Client Language to ja-JP. You can set the Client Language for each user in the User Manager, and a default in the web.config

```
      <!--  CLIENT LANGUAGE
            Specifies the default language of the Sitecore client if no language
            could be determined in any other way.
      -->
      <setting name="ClientLanguage" value="en"/>
```

Another point there is a \App_Config\Include\ja-JP.config.example file. maybe you have rename it to .config?

And there is a installed Japanese (ja-JP): [Client Translations](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Client_Translations/CMS%20Client%20Translations/7,-d-,5.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I have searched through the configs and do not have any mention of `ja-jp`. The only places I found it were search config files.